# How does one run Spawning with Django within a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, virtualenv, spawning

Because of the way Eventlet, which Spawning depends on, installs itself, it can't be installed into a virtualenv. The following error (wrapped for readability) illustrates:

```
Running eventlet-0.9.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir \
  /tmp/easy_install-m_s75o/eventlet-0.9.4/egg-dist-tmp-fAZK_u
error: SandboxViolation: chmod('/home/myuser/.python-eggs/\
  greenlet-0.2-py2.6-linux-i686.egg-tmp/tmpgxa_uc.$extract', 493) {}
```

Without patching the Python path beyond all recognition, and installing Spawning globally (which would break the whole point of having a virtualenv anyway), how would one install/run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following five commands worked without any problems. How are you installing spawning?

```
virtualenv test
cd test/
. bin/activate
easy_install spawning
python -c 'import spawning'
```

Comment: Hi Flavius, do we know each other? :)

Comment: Cool: I was just trying to run the Python interpreter without having my path altered, i.e: virtualenv/bin/easy_install etc...

Thanks!

Comment: The command ". bin/activate" or "source bin/activate" (the dot is just a shortcut) should alter your path... Anyway the main thing is that it's working now ;)